# Best way to make article content available offline using node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, offlineapps

What is the best way to make any kind of article/blog content to make available offline or make it readable more like pocket using node.js ?

How do I perform downloading whole page including it's resources for offline use.

Comment: parsing the index page of website then getting all the links from that then go into child pages is the idea to download a website

Answer (score 0):

the link https://nodejs.org/api/ has all the child pages

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Node.js v5.3.0 Manual &amp; Documentation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com   /css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/sh.css">
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://nodejs.org/api/index.html">
</head>
<body class="alt apidoc" id="api-section-index">
  <div id="content" class="clearfix">
   <div id="column2" class="interior">
     <div id="intro" class="interior">
    <a href="/" title="Go back to the home page">
      Node.js (1)
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
<li><a class="nav-documentation" href="documentation.html">About these Docs</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-synopsis" href="synopsis.html">Synopsis</a> </li>
<li><a class="nav-assert" href="assert.html">Assertion Testing</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-buffer" href="buffer.html">Buffer</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-addons" href="addons.html">C/C++ Addons</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-child_process" href="child_process.html">Child Processes</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-cluster" href="cluster.html">Cluster</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-console" href="console.html">Console</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-crypto" href="crypto.html">Crypto</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-debugger" href="debugger.html">Debugger</a> </li>
<li><a class="nav-dns" href="dns.html">DNS</a></li>
 <li><a class="nav-domain" href="domain.html">Domain</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-errors" href="errors.html">Errors</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-events" href="events.html">Events</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-fs" href="fs.html">File System</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-globals" href="globals.html">Globals</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-http" href="http.html">HTTP</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-https" href="https.html">HTTPS</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-modules" href="modules.html">Modules</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-net" href="net.html">Net</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-os" href="os.html">OS</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-path" href="path.html">Path</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-process" href="process.html">Process</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-punycode" href="punycode.html">Punycode</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-querystring" href="querystring.html">Query Strings</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-readline" href="readline.html">Readline</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-repl" href="repl.html">REPL</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-stream" href="stream.html">Stream</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-string_decoder" href="string_decoder.html">String Decoder</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-timers" href="timers.html">Timers</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-tls" href="tls.html">TLS/SSL</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-tty" href="tty.html">TTY</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-dgram" href="dgram.html">UDP/Datagram</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-url" href="url.html">URL</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-util" href="util.html">Utilities</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-v8" href="v8.html">V8</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-vm" href="vm.html">VM</a></li>
<li><a class="nav-zlib" href="zlib.html">ZLIB</a></li>
```

now call these pages by node.js

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;


client = new Client();

var fs = require('fs')


client.get("https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html",
function(data, response){
     console.log(data.toString());
});
```

now use fs to save the file